# Android, get the location update when the screen is off

Tags: java, android

I use a started service with the fused api, and implement the location listener directly on it. The Location keeps updating even when the screen is locked, But it stops if the screen goes off.

So, is there any way to make sure that the location will keep updating when the screen is off?

I read a lot of other questions and I don't really know what i'm missing.

```
    package com.trickyworld.locationupdates;

import android.Manifest;
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationChannel;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.location.Location;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.os.Looper;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat;


import com.google.android.gms.location.FusedLocationProviderClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationResult;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;

import java.io.Console;
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class LocationService extends Service {


   public static ArrayList<LatLng> locationArrayList = new ArrayList<LatLng>();

    FusedLocationProviderClient fusedLocationClient;
    LocationRequest locationRequest;
    LocationCallback locationCallback;

    private void startLocationUpdates() {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return;
        }
        fusedLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(locationRequest,
                locationCallback,
                Looper.getMainLooper());
    }

    protected void createLocationRequest() {
        LocationRequest locationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
        locationRequest.setInterval(3000);
        locationRequest.setFastestInterval(5000);
        locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        new Notification();

        fusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.O) createNotificationChanel() ;
        else startForeground(
                1,
                new Notification()
        );

        locationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
        locationRequest.setInterval(2000);
        locationRequest.setFastestInterval(2000);
        locationRequest.setMaxWaitTime(2000);
        locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);

        locationCallback = new LocationCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onLocationResult(@NonNull LocationResult locationResult) {
                Location location =  locationResult.getLastLocation();
                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                  //    "Lat: "+Double.toString(location.getLatitude()) + '\n' +
                    //    "Long: " + Double.toString(location.getLongitude()), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                Log.d("Mesage","Lat: "+Double.toString(location.getLatitude()) + '\n' +
                        "Long: " + Double.toString(location.getLongitude()));



                //locationArrayList.add(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()));

               /* for (Location location : locationResult.getLocations()) {
                  location
                }*/
            }
        };
        startLocationUpdates();
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    private void createNotificationChanel() {
        String notificationChannelId = "Location channel id";
        String channelName = "Background Service";

        NotificationChannel chan = new NotificationChannel(
                notificationChannelId,
                channelName,
                NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_NONE
        );
        chan.setLightColor(Color.BLUE);
        chan.setLockscreenVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PRIVATE);

        NotificationManager manager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);

        manager.createNotificationChannel(chan);

        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder =
               new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, notificationChannelId);

        Notification notification = notificationBuilder.setOngoing(true)
                .setContentTitle("Location updates:")
                .setPriority(NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_MIN)
                .setCategory(Notification.CATEGORY_SERVICE)
                .build();
        startForeground(2, notification);
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
        return START_REDELIVER_INTENT;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        fusedLocationClient.removeLocationUpdates(locationCallback);
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: You can try using a [WorkManager](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager).

Comment: I don't know about android studio much can you modify my code

Answer (score 0):

For Android 10+ you have to ask for another location permission - background location (see Google documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/training/location/background)). Apart from that check if the application is battery optimized - this might prevent background location too. And yet another thing is manufacturer specific optimization. Please check if phone is optimized. If so, it is very likely this prevent background location too.